# Google Tasks API clear tasklist in Python

Tags: python, api, task

I am trying to sync my command line list app written in Python with Google Tasks, now that there is a mobile version. I can list tasklists and get the proper ID, so I can successfully add tasks from my app to Google Tasks. However I cannot clear all the tasks in a tasklist. I am using the code right off the developer webpage:
https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/clear
The code is:
      `service.tasks().clear(tasklist='taskListID').execute()`

I have checked and double checked that I have the proper scope and tasklist ID. I get no errors or any response from Google, or any Python errors. When I supply the tasklist ID, and try the code on the "Try this API" form on the web page link included here, I get a "204 No content" error, though there are tasks visible in that tasklist, both in GMail and the mobile Tasks app.

Comment: I found a way to do it,not as simple as clear, but it works:      tasks = service.tasks().list(tasklist=taskid).execute()
for task in tasks['items']:                        service.tasks().delete(tasklist=listid,task=task['id']).execute()